# Binary Keyboard Layout

Tags: layout, keyboard, binary

I've recently informed myself a bit about keyboard layouts and tried things like Dvorak or Neo, but today i asked myself the question wether there is a sort of 'binary' keyboard layout.

It should use 8 keys to key in the binary representation of one character (one byte).

Example:

```
  ASDF and JKL; are used for input.
```

If want to write an `'A'` (65 decimal, 10000001 binary)
you had to press `A` and ;

Or you wanted to write an `'f'` (146 decimal, 10010010 binary)
you had to press `A`, `F` and `L`.

I wondered if there was already something like this or somebody could show me a  `C/C++` library capable of altering the keaboard layout and supporting combinations like these.

Comment: I'm wondering how you'd distinguish `a` (`110 0001`) from `@!` (`100 0000 | 010 0001`)

Comment: What about AutoHotKey?

Comment: Many keyboards couldn't support this. You often can't press down more than three or four keys at a time.

Comment: @JanDvorak Hm, I'll try using AHK, thx

Comment: @meagar Then you could use more buttons to represent the byte in another base for example, if you could only press four keys at once you had to use 16 buttons wich could be split into 2 sections of 8 buttons of wich only 2 can be pressed at once